# Why Real-time Database not updates?

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

```
   addDevice(deviceId: string, fireId: string){
    let Token: string;
    let UserId: string;
    let newDevice: Device;
    return this.authSrv.userId.pipe(take(1),
      switchMap(
        userId => {
          UserId = userId;
          return this.authSrv.token;
        }
      ),take(1),
      switchMap(
        token => {
          if(!UserId){
            throw new Error('No user id found');
          }
          Token = token;
          return this.http.get<DeviceData>(`https://....firebaseio.com/device/${fireId}.json? 
          auth=${token}`)
        }
      ),
      switchMap(
        deviceData => {
          if(!deviceData){
            throw new Error('No Device Id found or Pass Id incorrect');
          }
          newDevice = new Device(
              fireId, 
              deviceData.deviceId,
              deviceData.ver,
              deviceData.slot,
              UserId
          );
          this.http.put(`https://....firebaseio.com/device/${fireId}.json?auth=${Token}`,
            {...newDevice, id:null}
          );
          return this.devices;
        }
      )
    );
  }
```

the "get()" got my data but "put()" not do anything to my Firebase it also not showing any error i try use "console.log" to see data input.

i follow this code as my base

```
 places => {
  const upPlaceIndex = places.findIndex(pl => pl.id == placeId);
  upPlace = [...places];
  const oldPlace = upPlace[upPlaceIndex];
  upPlace[upPlaceIndex] = new Place(.....);
  return this.http.put(`https://....firebaseio.com/offers-places/${placeId}.json? 
  auth=${fetchToken}`, 
  {...upPlace[upPlaceIndex], id: null}
 }
```

which this code is work in my other project

Answer (score 0):

never mind i got it even through i don't understand it why

```
    switchMap(
        deviceData => {
          if(!deviceData){
            throw new Error('No Device Id found or Pass Id incorrect');
          }
          newDevice = new Device(
              fireId, 
              deviceData.deviceId,
              deviceData.ver,
              deviceData.slot,
              UserId
          );
          this.http.put(`https://....firebaseio.com/device/${fireId}.json?auth=${Token}`,
            {...newDevice, id:null}
          );
          return this.devices;
        }
      )
```

i just change it to this

```
switchMap(
        deviceData => {
          if(!deviceData){
            throw new Error('No Device Id found or Pass Id incorrect');
          }
          newDevice = new Device(
              fireId, 
              deviceData.deviceId,
              deviceData.ver,
              deviceData.slot,
              UserId
          );
          return this.http.put(`https://....firebaseio.com/device/${fireId}.json?auth=${Token}`,
            {...newDevice, id:null}
          );
        }
      ),
     switchMap(
      data => {
        return this.devices;
      }
     )
```